# Difficulties restricting access to my backend

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

I currently have a GKE Cluster running my frontend (Angular) and my backend (Nodejs / Adonisjs), I configured Cloud Armor with Allow policy using this condition

```
request.headers['origin'].matches('https://subdomain.domain.cl')
```

It works fine returning HTTP CODE 403 but if I make a query using Postman setting the origin header as https://subdomain.domain.cl bypass the security of Cloud Armor.

Since my frontend runs on the client side, I don't have a static ip address to allow connections, what can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: I think POSTman override the origin header with something else. Can you log and verify the value of origin header at your backend (which I believe is behind loadbalancer to which you attach cloud armor security policy)

Answer (score 0):

Can you implement CORS to allow and restrct domains

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

for example

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
 
var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://example.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
}
```

To allow only from http://example.com